# How to reflect scala tuple type variable?

Tags: scala, reflection

I am using 2.10.4.

I need to reflect a Tuple's type variable so that I can create a Tuple instance dynamically and with the arguments of the right type. So far I only manage to reflect the Type variables  (T1, T2) as shown in my test case below as such I am not able to prevent unwanted type value to be inserted into the newly instantiated Tuple.

Any help is greatly appreciated

```
package scala.reflect

import org.scalatest.FunSuite

class ReflectTupleType extends FunSuite {

    import scala.reflect.runtime._
    import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  def reflect[T](arg1: Any, arg2: Any)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): T = {

      val ru = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
      val ctxcl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
      val mirr = runtimeMirror(ctxcl)

      val classSym = typeOf[T].typeSymbol.asClass
      val classMirr = mirr.reflectClass(classSym)

      val ctorMethodSym = typeOf[T].declaration(nme.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
      val paramTypeList = ctorMethodSym.paramss.head map (_.typeSignature)
      println("paramTypeList " + paramTypeList) //Type variables not Type

      val ctorm = classMirr.reflectConstructor(ctorMethodSym)
      val tuple2 = ctorm(arg1, arg2)
      tuple2.asInstanceOf[T]
  }

  test("tuple") {

      val validTup2 = reflect[(String, Int)]("Test", 1) //This is valid

      println("Should be valid " + validTup2)

      val invalidTup2 = reflect[(String, Int)]("Test", "a")  //This is not valid - wrong type

      println("Should be invalid " +invalidTup2)
  }    
}
```

Comment: It looks like type erasure is making these runtime type-checks impossible.

Comment: When you save a type tag, erasure stops being a problem.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your use case? How do you plan to use this methods? Do the argument have type Any, or you know a bit more about them?

Comment: I managed to figure out by using TypeRef
val TypeRef(prefix, c, typeArgs) = typeTag[M].tpe  

I am trying to create instances of T, be it case class or Tuple so that I can bind the result set from a database query